# How to handle duplicate messages in Kafka

Tags: python, apache-kafka

I know duplicate messages can produce on both the producer side and the consumer side.
And I also know, Kafka deduplicates messages on the producer side by enabling idempotency.
But how about the consumer side?
I see two different solutions:

1. Writing idempotent consumer if possible
2. Keep the message ID in the consumer's database to ignore duplicate messages.
   The first solution is not possible in my case, and the second one does not have benefits.
   For example, we have the following code:

```
message = consumer.poll()
save_order(message.order)
consumer.commit()
```

And after implementing the second solution we change the code like this:

```
message = consumer.poll()

if is_duplicate(message.id):
  return
 
save_order(message.order)
save_message_id(message.id)
consumer.commit()
```

Ok, now nothing goes wrong if the consumer crashes before `consumer.commit()`. But wait, what happens if the consumer crashes before `save_message_id(message.id)`?
I think we gain nothing!

Of course, we can use transactions to ensure `save_order()` and `save_message_id()` are done atomically, but we don't have this option in some cases (for example if we need to just call an API in the consumer without any database operation).

Is there any other option? How do big companies handle this? Why we don't see duplicate transactions in the banks?

Comment: _Why we don't see duplicate transactions in the banks_ - Because banks don't use **only** Kafka. Every company I worked for did store the **processed** IDs in the database. If the consumer fails, record is not processed, so it is fine to consume again

Comment: agree with @OneCricketeer. The service you'd want for this should take pride in quick read/writes like RocksDB or Redis

Comment: @OneCricketeer Thanks. When and Where store these IDs? If we store them before the process, what happens if the consumer breaks after that, if we store them at the end of the process, the consumer may fail before it. If we store it atomically everything is fine but just for DB operations, not for example an API call.

Comment: @Nerm Thanks, increasing read/write speed just decreases the chance of duplication, does not remove it.

Comment: When you like to communicate with some external service you most often use Transactional Outbox pattern and save message to sent with kafka message id within single transaction, and forward message to external system in separate thread. That way you achieve at least once consistency, so external system needs to be idempotent too.

Comment: More info - https://microservices.io/patterns/data/transactional-outbox.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As Paweł Szymczyk and OneCricketeer said in the comments, we should use the [Transactional Outbox](https://microservices.io/patterns/data/transactional-outbox.html) pattern in these cases.
Using this pattern we can even convert non-database operations to database operations too.
For example, we can use the Transactional Outbox pattern to trigger another event that calls an API instead of calling it directly.